# Rand() not unique in C

Tags: c, random

I am using a rand() function to generate a random chocolate. Even though I have seeded the time, rand() always gives me the same number and I'm not sure how to fix it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>


int main() {
    /* Seed the random number generator */
    srand48(time(0));
    double t=rand()%5;
    printf("Your selected chocolate will be: \n");
    if(t==0){
        printf("Caramel\n");
    }
    else if(t==1){
        printf("Milk\n");
    }
    else if(t==2){
        printf("Sweet\n");
    }
    else if(t==3){
        printf("Semi-sweet\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Dark\n");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `srand48` is not `srand`. In other words, always check the man pages to make sure you are using the correct function.

Comment: If you don't seed it, `rand()` will produce the same sequence every time, yes. You need to call `srand()` to do that...

Comment: Use lrand48() instead of rand()

Comment: In case you're not understanding the other comments, `srand48()` seeds the `lrand48()` function, and `srand()` seeds the `rand()` function. You have to use the correct pair of functions together.

Comment: Even if you manage to seed your randoms, comparing a double to constant for identity might end up in the "else" branch. Use an integer instead.

Comment: Also note that with even the best RNG, you'll have problems with a program that only uses one number; it won't really be random at all, it will be a hash function of the time. For example, if two users run this program within a second of each other, they'll get the same answer. Better to use an external randomness source like /dev/random.

Comment: @Yunnosch: Comparing floating-point numbers for equality has its pitfalls, but I don't see a problem here. The possible values of `t` are 0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0 and 4.0. all of them can be represented exactly and should compare as equal to the respective integers. (But I'm not saying that `double` is a good choice for the type of ´t`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have noted in the comments, the function `srand48` does not seed `rand`; it seeds `lrand48` and related functions. From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/srand48):

> The srand48(), seed48() and lcong48() functions are initialization functions, one of which should be called before using drand48(), lrand48() or mrand48(). The functions erand48(), nrand48() and jrand48() do not require an initialization function to be called first.

You need to call [`srand`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/srand) with the argument `time(0)` to seed the `rand` function to the current system time.

Also, why are you using the type `double` to store the value returned from `rand`? Use whichever integral type is sufficient to contain `RAND_MAX` on your system; usually `short` or `int`.